# Is there a way to allow the user to access the titlebar when in fullscreen mode of a WinUI app?

Tags: maui, winui-3, winui

My application (.NET MAUI) used to have a fullscreen function in UWP that I have since redone since it changed in WinUI APIs.

The problem with this method is that it hides the titlebar of the window (which has the back button, close button etc). On UWP, this titlebar was still accessible by hovering near the top of the screen. Is it possible on WinUI to give the user access to a fullscreen mode similar to UWP that allows them to go back, close the app, exist fullscreen etc?

This is my code for using fullscreen on WinUI:

```cs
        var appWindow = GetAppWindow();

        if (appWindow == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // set the Windows preference and immediately switch fullscreen mode
        if (fullscreen)
        {
            appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
        }
        else
        {
            appWindow.SetPresenter(AppWindowPresenterKind.Default);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `OverlappedPresenter` to maximize the screen as well as showing a title bar. Try below code the following line in MauiProgram.cs.

```
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {
#if WINDOWS
            events.AddWindows(windows =>
            {
                windows.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    WindowId windowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
                    var appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
                        
                    //Use presenter to determine the look and feel of the window.                  
                    switch (appWindow.Presenter)
                    {
                        case OverlappedPresenter overlappedPresenter:
                            overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(true, true);
                            overlappedPresenter.Maximize();
                            break;
                    }
                });
            });
#endif
        });
```

> That `AppWindow` has a Presenter, right now through .NET MAUI, we always
> set that presenter to the `OverlappedPresenter`. That is why there is
> only one option in the switch statement. This presenter determines the
> look and feel of the window.

Here we set the full screen using `overlappedPresenter.Maximize();` and since you want to have a titlebar to perform navigation, you may set `overlappedPresenter.SetBorderAndTitleBar(true, true);`

---

Update

Fullscreen mode and maximized are different states on Windows. Maximized does have a titlebar while fullscreen mode doesn't. If you want Fullscreen mode with a title bar popup in maui, you could raise a feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui).